# pouchdb replication not completing, just stuck with pending docs

Tags: ionic3, couchdb, pouchdb

I am trying to do filtered replication in my Ionic 3 app, but after reading some docs it gets stuck with pending docs and the complete event is also not fired. This happens when I build and run the app on mobile.

The app running with `ionic serve` is working fine.

App:

> Ionic 3
>   PouchDB(6.4.3) with cordova-sqlite plugin(2.0.3)
>   couch version: 2.1.2

Config

```
 PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-find').default);
      PouchDB.plugin(cordovaSqlitePlugin);
      this.db = new PouchDB(gstin, {
        adapter: 'cordova-sqlite', location: 'default'
      });
```

Replication options:

```
{
  filter: 'Generic/xxxxx',
  query_params: {
    id: xxx,
    deviceId: xxxx
  },
  batch_size: 10
}
```

Last change console,

```
{
 ok: true,
 start_time: "2018-09-07T09:18:16.204Z",
 docs_read: 136,
 docs_written: 136,
 doc_write_failures: 0, …}
 doc_write_failures:0
 docs:(11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
 docs_read:136
 docs_written:136
 errors:Array(0)
 length:0
  __proto__:Array(0)
 last_seq:"xxxxxx"
 ok:true
 pending:402
 start_time:"2018-09-07T09:18:16.204Z"
 __proto__:Object
```

Comment: Replication works fine till the time I was not fetching attachment, I tried with fresh couchdb but it stops working as soon as it tries to replicate attachments

Answer (score 0):

Tinkering with PouchDb/CouchDb, while learning to use them together, can leave synchronization pointers in a weird state.

May I suggest you experiment with completely fresh instances of your databases?

I found it necessary to create CURL scripts to completely rebuild my test databases before expending any serious effort to track down why something wasn't working.

I believe you could get more help here if you were to show the filter you are using, and the full code of the replication command, rather than just the options.

**Update**: I also strongly recommend you create a simple CouchDb server (or a free tier Cloudant database) and create a very simple browser app with default service (rather than cordova-sqlite) and test your assumptions about how replication works.

Comment: After enabling dubugging I found out that if db contains any blob, then only its failing to replicate

Comment: As a basic courtesy to people who take time trying to help you, and to those seeking solutions to similar difficulties, you really should **always** answer your own question as you as you discover a solution.

Comment: I am still not able to solve the issue, its still an open issue, I just added comment to provide additional information

Comment: Ah ok!  I jumped to a wrong conclusion.  I am eager to help, but I would like to know that you have tried my original (and just now updated) suggestions.  I am also wrestling with filtered replication and have found the documentation to be scattered and full of frustrating ambiguities.  If we can help each other I would be glad of a collaborator.